# Entrevista con nuestro CM, Nicolas

Tags: discusión, gerente-de-comunidad

Hace unos días [@Jon Ericson](https://stackexchange.com/users/1083/jon-ericson) publicó una entrevista a nuestro CM [@Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://stackexchange.com/users/272910/nicolas-chabanovsky) que puede resultar interesante.

Eso sí, debo indicar que es en un perfecto inglés, así que se debe ser conocedor de la lengua de Shakespeare para disfrutar de ella.

La charla está [aqui](https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/episodes/nicolas.mp3).

[Enlace a la noticia en Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332176/346768)